# how to change values in a string with a particular value using regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

have a df with values

```
    0               1 
0 RS 125       | password1
1 EURO 25      | password2
2 DNR 30       | password3
```

Using regex how to change values of these at once likes the values after RS,EURO,DNR should be replace with 100

output should be

```
    0               1 
0 RS 100       | password1
1 EURO 100      | password2
2 DNR 100      | password3
```

Tried this

```
def Currency(0):

    pattern = re.compile("(Rs |EURO |DNR |)")
    result = pattern.match(name)
```

Trying to replace the matched ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'(?i)((?:Rs|EURO|DNR)\s*)\d+', r'\g<1>100')
```

Or, if you want to match the currency names as whole words, prepend the capturing group with a word boundary `\b`:

```
r'(?i)\b((?:Rs|EURO|DNR)\s*)\d+'
      ^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AFNjMJ/2).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive flag
- `((?:Rs|EURO|DNR)\s*)` - Group 1 (`\g<1>` in the replacement pattern refers to this value):

  - `(?:Rs|EURO|DNR)` - `Rs` or `EURO` or `DNR`
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\d+` - one or more digits

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AFNjMJ/1).